# Cow in glass looks broken

Tags: materials

[image: Broken glass]

So the cow wrapped around the glass looks broken .I wanna make it looking clear. If tried changing IO and roughness but no luck, or it looks mat or its almost invisible. Any idea somebody?

Comment: how did you do it, does it have enough geometry to bend?

Comment: I added a plane and cut the cow out of it then i wrapped it around the glass

Comment: Can you post a shot of the wireframe

Comment: Its only on the edge